# Assiociate Widgets into Groups, for Hide and Show, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a bunch of widgets and right now I am using Hide() and Show() to each widget individually when I flip through different sections/pages of my program.

Because I did this, You can see each widget leaving/showing one by one (which kinda sucks).

Is there anyway to group all these widgets and then be able to Hide() and Show() this group, to avoid this "one by one" habit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Freeze/Thaw/Layout when you are showing and hiding the widgets. This way they should all appear/disappear at the same time.

Comment: +1 great. however from docs: This method .... is not implemented on all platforms nor for all controls so it is mostly just a hint to wxWindows and not a mandatory directive.

Comment: this works pretty well for me, though as joaquin said, its not supported on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Put your group of widgets organized in a sizer in the same parent container (p.e. a panel) and hide the parent. All the widgets disappear with the parent.

Note that sometimes hiding (for example) buttons or checkboxes is not the best solution. Available functionality for the user can be also modulated using `widget.Disable()`

Comment: Is there another way todo this without using a panel. The widgets are a little unorganized

Comment: You usually want a panel or you'll lose correct tabbing behavior cross-platform